# Any other unique identifier beside IP address from a Meteor client request?

Tags: http, meteor

I'm working on a Meteor application that actually allows anonymous users to interact with the application in a minimal way (yes I know this is dangerous - I've setup the proper limitations and security enforcements.)

One thing I was doing was using an anonymous user's IP address (using `this.connection.clientAddress` in a Meteor method) as an identifier to track how many interactions they had and enforcing certain limitations.

I realized that if any number of anonymous users are behind the same router/WiFi they will all have the same public IP address.

Is there any other unique identifiable information that can be read from a client request?  I noticed the `this.connection` has an `httpHeaders` attribute which may have a `remoteAddress` property in it.  Even a `remoteAddress` may not be unique since there could be multiple WiFi networks distributing the same internal IP addresses (e.g. `192.168.0.101`). 
Maybe combining both of these would work?
In looking at the `httpHeaders` object inside a Meteor method it looks like it contains an `x-forwarded-for` property that has the local IP address of the request and also has a `host` property that is the local IP of my Meteor server. This could possibly work if the `x-forwarded-for` is always the client's internal IP address - but this could also be the IP address of a router in the path to getting to my Meteor server right?

I'm assuming the user's MAC address would not be in the request coming into my Meteor server right?

In light of this, the only alternative I can think of is to create some kind of `AnonymousUsers` collection and when an anonymous user connects and chooses to stay anonymous, I would create an instance of `AnonymousUser` and save `anonymousUser._id` into the user's `Session` and use that as an `id` for all the anonymous user's interactions.  This will stay with them while they're connected.  If they refresh, then they'll just get a new `AnonymousUser` instance.  Then I could have a cron job that runs every so often that removes `AnonymousUser` instances that aren't connected to anything else in the app (anonymous users who never did anything in the app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
if ( !Session.get('anonId') ) Session.set('anonId',Random.id());
```

and use that as your identifier.

You can also set a cookie using the same `Random.id()` to generate a random string and then that can last across multiple visits assuming first party cookies are allowed by that user.

[docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/random).

Comment: The main reason I was thinking of making another collection was so I could get a randomly generated unique id.  Forgot you could just `Random.id()`.  Nice one.  Though, one of the benefits of having an additional `AnonymousUser` collection is I could attach a user input "handle/name" to it (e.g. FunGuy24, Jane Doe, etc.) and then represent that anonymous user by their handle - even after they've disconnected.  This is good tho.